# Disprove that $V$ is a linear subspace of $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Disprove that $V$ is a linear subspace of $R^3$, where $V$ = {$(x, y, z)$ ∈ $R^3$ : $x + 2y = 0$ or $5x − z = 0$}.

So here $dim$ = 2, $basis$ = { $(1, 2, 0), (5, 0, -1)$ } if I understand it correctly.

So it is a subspace of $R^3$.

Or am I mistaken here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, that is not the basis -- the basis isn't simply putting the coefficients into the right slots. For instance, $(1,2,0)$ does not satisfy $x+2y=0$.

Secondly, if we write $u=(2,-1,0)$ and $v=(1,0,5)$, then clearly both vectors are in $V$. What is $u+v$? $(3,-1,5)$ of course, but this satisfies neither equation one nor equation two. Thus the subspace is not linear.

Comment: The vectors are not in $V$.  They need to satisfy both equations at once.

Comment: @ChrisCuster I'm not sure? It says "or" not "and", right?

Comment: Oh you're right.  I didn't catch that.  If it's "or" you're right.